# Why are golang semicolons optional before a close parenthesis?

Tags: go

According to the [Go documentation](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Semicolons) a semicolon is optional if it is just before a `)` or `}`.

> To allow complex statements to occupy a single line, a semicolon may be omitted before a closing ")" or "}".

I understand how the `}` rule allows one liners such as the following:

```
if x { return 1 }
```

But what is the purpose of the `)` rule? What kind of statement or other semicolon thing can appear just before a close parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find where semicolons can appear before a closing parenthesis,
search the [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec) for the text `";" } ")"`.

Examples:

```
import ( "fmt"; )
var ( v int; )
const ( c = 1; )
type ( t []int; )
```